# firebase error when connection to android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, gradle, build.gradle

hello people i have just got an error when i connect my flutter project to firebase and i have latest version of android studio and flutterSDK
this is the error

C:\Users\Texas Electronics Lt\newsdkproject>flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on SO 03J in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':firebase_core:classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> Required by:
> project :firebase_core
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.1.2/gradle-8.1.2.pom
> > Resetting to invalid mark
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_core' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 20s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            324.4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

C:\Users\Texas Electronics Lt\newsdkproject>

i tried to update android studio version

Comment: Have you added or updated the google JSON file in the android folder?